# Is $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(I+J)$ integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

Let $I=\left<X-2\right>, J=\left<X+2\right>$. Is $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(I+J)$ integral domain?

We have a theorem which says: $I\triangleleft P$ is prime ideal iff $P/I$ is domain.

So, in this case, we can prove if $I+J$ is prime ideal. How should I do it? Thank you.

Comment: See that for every pair of ideals $I\subseteq J$ of $R$  we have $R/J\subset R/I$... As $I\subseteq I+J$, we have $$\mathbb{Z}[X]/(I+J)\subseteq \mathbb{Z}[X]/I=\mathbb{Z}$$ which is an integral domain... Thus, being a subring of integral domain, $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(I+J)$ is an integral domain.. Is this ok??  This is meant for OP. Others please excuse..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik No, it's not ok! Your inclusion is wrong. In fact, the given ring is not an integral domain since $4\in I+J$. Furthermore, the quotient ring is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

As $X+2-(X-2)=4\in I+J$, we must have

$$(2+I+J)(2+I+J)=(4+I+J)=(0+I+J)$$

However, $2+I+J\neq 0+I+J$, as $2\notin I+J$. So, it is not an integral domain.

**Edit**: Why $2\notin I+J$? Suppose it is, then there are $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$ such that

$$p(X)(X+2)+q(X)(X-2)=2$$

Now, $p(2)(2+2)+q(2)(2-2)=2$, so $4p(2)=2$, contradiction.